# How to know the installed Software version in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I wanted to know what version of software(say X software) installed in my system with PowerShell. In my case, I wanted to know what version of Service Fabric SDK installed in my system with PowerShell.

Comment: See if this link helps: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software/

Answer (score 3):

if your process/software is run , use this command :

```
Get-Process -Name "xsoftware" | Format-list -Property ProductVersion
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this approach.  I did a bit of experimenting and found a couple of caveats that others should be aware of.  1) This assumes that the app/service is actually running.  2) the "ProductVersion" property isn't necessarily available depending upon the process that you are checking.  For example, the "mongod" (MongoDB) process in our environment doesn't have the "ProductVersion" property.

Answer (score 3):

In our case, we needed to verify if MongoDB was installed on multiple servers, and if so, what version.  We used a simple PowerShell command and pushed it out multiple servers via Ansible/AWX.  Here's the command:

`Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*MongoDB*"}   | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | Format-List;`

Answer (score 0):

This link highlight very well what the issues are with using the WMI approach and then outlines a solution for using the registry. The way he does the registry also allows for calling it against remote machines.

https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/07/27/gathering-installed-software-using-powershell.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use WMI to get information of an installed product. To do this filter by the `Name`. For example, to get information of Word:

```
$product = gwmi win32_product -filter "Name LIKE '%Word%'"
```

You will then find the version information in the `Version` property:

```
$product.Version
```

NOTE: The WMI lookups can be a bit slow, so be patient!

Comment: Downvoted (not personal) because Win32_product is broken : it forces a re-register on all registered MSI packages (which sometimes cause a "repair" which can result in a loss of settings of the application). This has been broken for years and the use of this WMI class should be avoided. Crawling through the registry is the better solution.

Comment: @bluuf - they maybe you should contribute something by writing it up as an answer...

Comment: Everything regarding the win32_product (and why it's bad) and the registry workaround is written up on the "Hey Scripting Guy" blog on https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software/ (because I didn't write this code I don't want to "steal" an answer with code written by someone else). Again, the downvote was nothing personal : I just want people to prevent using this broken class since it can cause more unexpected problems when querying it.

Comment: @bluff, can you give an example to know the installed sdk versionl or can you give an example with registry

Comment: @shri : look at the link that I've provided (it links to the MS hey scripting guy blog) that contains a workaround using the registry